# Random "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, networking

We are experiencing very unusual behavior when calling a WCF service. The problem is that **sometimes** it works, and then **sometimes** we get the following error (all inner exceptions combined):

> An error occurred while making the HTTP request to . This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.
>
> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>
> Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

**We found out the following case:** The service call works normally when repeating it a few times in intervals of 1 second. Then after waiting for 2-3 minutes, the exception occurs and it keeps occurring for a long time (we didn't determine that). After it starts working the whole procedure can be repeated to get the exception again.

**This happens only when we are connecting through a company's firewall.** If we connect directly to the server everything works as expected.

Everything happens only when calling function **SaveBathroom**, other functions work normally. We suspect that it may be because of the big message size.

```
//Function on the server that fails *sometimes*
public ConfigurationSaveStatus SaveBathroom(BathroomConfiguration bathroom);

//Function that never fails
public UpdateInfo[] GetUpdates(string xml, string langauge, System.DateTime lastUpdateCheckDate);

//Interface:
public enum ConfigurationSaveStatus {...}

public class BathroomConfiguration
{
    public string BathroomNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime ConfigurationDate { get; set; }
    public Version ClientVersion { get; set; }
    public bool ScenarioReady { get; set; }
    public bool ScenarioActivated { get; set; }
    public string LicenseXml { get; set; }
    public byte[] ConfigurationReportPdf { get; set; }
    public string Configuration { get; set; }
    public string eToolMac { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string SubCategory { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string FileLocation { get; set; }
    public long FileSize { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ValidTo { get; set; }
}

//config
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IeAssistService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                        maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                        allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                                                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IeAssistService"
                contract="IeAssistService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IeAssistService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: When exceptions start coming try iisreset on server. Does all requests still fail, or some of them start working again and then after some time requests start failing again?

Comment: We found out that this s a firewall problem. The request does not reach the service at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was a bit tricky.

First we found out that the firewall is blocking the request. Microsoft Forefront Threat Management Gateway used Certificate login with fallback to username/password login.

The client was using username/password credentials. It seems that there is a bug at TMG with big messages and this sort of configuration, so the TMG closed the connection by itself. Sometimes. And refused new connections of the same type for some time.

As soon as we disabled the certificate login, everything was fine.